# My ads are only visible in landscape?

Tags: android, landscape

Well I uploaded an app on the market, but the ads were showing only on tablets, not on phones. But then I tilted my phone in landscape instead of portrait and the ad popped? I cannot understand why is that here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/blue_final2"
>
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="ID"   
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        />

<ScrollView android:layout_weight="30" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="9" >
<ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/ibOne"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="3"
       android:src="@drawable/one"
       android:background="@null"
       android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ibTwo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:src="@drawable/two" 
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"/>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ibThree"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:src="@drawable/three"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView1"
   android:padding="30dp"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Click on the picture you like the most and see your result!"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
   android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: do you have a `layout-land` folder inside of `res`?

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out. It was quite simple... I just changed the width of the ad to wrap_content to match parent and everything is working properly!